# ServerSocket.accept() on host does not accept connection originating in guest VM

Tags: java, tcp, virtual-machine, serversocket

In my Java app, I have the following code:

```
_serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
_serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
_serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
// _serverSocket = ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=33202]
_socket = _serverSocket.accept();
...
```

In a VM, I launch a (black box) client application that tries to connect to the above server. For an unknown reason, no connection is established and accept never returns.

I know the client app is trying to connect, as I see appropriate packets in Wireshark:
[image: Wireshark screen capture]

I can't launch the same client application on my host machine but I can successfully establish a TCP connection from the host with `nc`, so I know the server is actually listening.
The VM and host are in the 10.11.1.0 subnet. The host has IP 10.11.1.1, the VM 10.11.1.68. They can ping each other.

But still, for some reason, the TCP packets do not seem to arrive at my Java code. Any ideas why or how I could further debug this?

Comment: Probably a software firewall blocking on the host.

Comment: Can you use nc to connect from the **guest** (i.e. inside the VM) to your java app? If not, it could be a firewall blocking you as Andreas pointed out, or a VM network adapter setting. In Virtualbox for example, some network adapter modes will not let guests connect to arbitrary ports on the host if I recall correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, the guest OS is a severely limited Windows. I could write a tiny Java application that does what I would do with nc.

Comment: Windows usually has telnet (or you can install it as a Windows Feature from the 'Programs and Feautres' item in the control panel), so you dont need to write a separate app. You should also check / disable the Windows firewall on the guest to see if that makes any impact.

Comment: @Andreas It was indeed the firewall. See my solution below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I could solve my problem. It was indeed a problem with the host's Windows Firewall settings. After adding an inbound rule for `javaw.exe` of the specific JDK I was using to run the server, the connection could be established successfully.

Shout out to Corporate IT that didn't just let me disable the firewall quickly to determine if that was the cause of the problem. :\